# Linq Select projection cannot be applied to single record

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying return the year from a string array if it contains any matching year.

The GetYear() extension method is as follows:

```
public static int GetYear(this string me)
{
  for (int i = 1971; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
  {
    if (me.Equals(i.ToString()))
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This works

```
string[] splitString = me.Split(' ');
var year = splitString.Select(x => x.GetYear()).FirstOrDefault(x => x > 0);
```

But this doesn't

```
string[] splitString = me.Split(' ');
var year = splitString.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetYear() > 0).Select(x => x.GetYear());
```

I would like to know why it does not work as Select<>() is supposed to be a projection right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second query gives design time error as x does not contain a method GetYear()

Comment: just flip them around.  splitString.select(x => x.GetYear()).FirstOrDefault(x => x > 0)

Comment: @Steve, that was what I did in my question. Just wondering why it doesn't work the other way around

Comment: Look to Bradly Moorfield's answer, FirstOrDefault returns a single item, LINQ extensions methods only work on bjects that inherit the IEnumable interface.   In your case, an INT does not implement this interface, while Select() does return IEnumerable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns a single element from an `IEnumerable`

When it is used in the second case which is a `string[]`, it returns a `string`

Using `Select` on a `string` projects each character of the string, and your extension method doesn't exist for `char` types